# Where do I save my ruby (.rb) files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, command

I am receiving the error No such file or directory in my command line and I think it's because I am not saving the ruby files somewhere specific. All I did was create a random folder where I would save my ruby files.

Do I need to save my scripts in the original ruby folder? Thanks!

** This is Windows 7.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error and stack trace? Maybe even provide some context like what you were doing or trying to do when you got the error.

Comment: *What* command/error exactly raises error?

Comment: All I did was make a simple file named "Matz.rb" because I'm currently reading the O'reilly Ruby book. In my code all I wrote waas puts "Hello Matz". I saved this on my desktop. When I go to the command line it and I write ruby matz.rb it says "ruby: No such file or directory -- matz.rb <loaderror>" Please help :(

Comment: Wow, exactly the same question and exactly the same original poster?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can save your .rb files anywhere you can write. If you want to access a script no matter what your current directory, put the script in a directory that is part of your shell's PATH.

Are you comfortable using the shell on your machine? If not, you should learn a little about how to navigate directories, how commands are found, and the like. It will pay dividends.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly what a shell & PATH is? I literally just started learning Ruby last night.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows, OS X, something else?

Comment: ** This is Windows 7. - directly from his question @Fred

Comment: Oooh, yeah, I missed that. Sorry Alexander Tekle. The shell is a program that lets you 'talk' to the operating system. You give commands, it displays the result of running the command. For example, if you type in 'dir' that is the directory command, and Windows will display the names of the files in the current directory. The PATH is a list of directories which Windows will search automatically for programs and scripts. It would be worthwhile to check out Mr. Google for a Windows shell tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, depending on how your editor is set up, you may have the extension of .txt appended to your file, and so when you go to run `Matz.rb` it doesn't really exist, it is really `` `Matz.rb.txt ``.

This may or may not be happening with you, but a way to check is to open your command prompt, and do a `dir` in the folder to see what files you have there.

Comment: How can I do a "dir" and what does that do?

Comment: On Windows, you would click on the Start menu, select the "Run" option, type in `cmd.exe`.  Navigate to your folder and type `dir`.  Otherwise, go to your File Explorer, go to the options, change the option to view extensions for all files.  Not sure what the actual nomenclature is for the OS.