# How do I save a ruby file? (error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, command

I am receiving the error No such file or directory in my command line and I think it's because I am not saving the ruby files somewhere specific. All I did was create a random folder where I would save my ruby files.

Do I need to save my scripts in the original ruby folder? Thanks!

** This is Windows 7.

More info - 
All I did was make a simple file named "Matz.rb" because I'm currently reading the O'reilly Ruby book. In my code all I wrote was puts "Hello Matz". I saved this on my desktop. When I go to the command line it and I write ruby matz.rb it says "ruby: No such file or directory -- matz.rb " Please help :(

If this has something to do with PATH or shells, I honestly have no idea what those really are because I just started coding last night.

Comment: Install Ruby,using Rubyinstaller.. then run your `.rb` file from any directory like `ruby test.rb`.. it will work...

Comment: I've already installed ruby.

Comment: If you use Rubyinstaller and set all the options during installations,then such error should not come...

Comment: Can you explain where I save my files though please? maybe that's why

Comment: What happens if you try to run `ruby --version`? I'd like to check if it's ruby that isn't being found, or matz.rb that isn't being found by the ruby interpreter.

Comment: Can you show window path variable content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do I save my ruby (.rb) files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024309/where-do-i-save-my-ruby-rb-files)

Comment: @AlexanderTekle When you need to add additional information to your question, you can just edit your original question. You don't have to create a new one.

Comment: Mark Embling it says I have 2.0.0p195....

Babai what exactly is a path variable content, I'm really new to programming.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell oh sorry, I just joined.

Comment: @AlexanderTekle No worries. Just letting you know so you can learn for next time. Since you are just starting out, StackOverflow will be your best friend ever. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely not in the right folder. You somehow need to tell the ruby interpreter where it is looking for the file.

Either make sure you're in the right folder - the `cd` command allows you to change location:

```
cd C:\Users\Username\Desktop
ruby Matz.rb
```

or specify the path explicitly:

```
ruby C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Matz.rb
```

By default, the ruby interpreter will look in your current directory (the location shown in your prompt) for whatever filename you give it.

---

**Edit:** I'll attempt to explain what I mean step-by-step.

- When you initially open the command prompt, it will indicate what folder you are in (your "current working directory") in the prompt:

  ```
  C:\Users\YourUsername >
  ```

  In the above example, you are working in the `C:\Users\YourUsername` folder.
- You can move directories using the `cd` command. For example, typing `cd Desktop` moves you into the folder called `Desktop`, **assuming such a folder exists in your current location**
- You can move to another folder *outside* your current folder by specifying explicitly where you want to be: `cd C:\Another\Place`
- When you run a ruby command such as `ruby Matz.rb`, the system knows how to find the `ruby` program because the installer placed its location into the `PATH` environment variable. Don't worry about this too much, this just explains the "magic" by which it knows what `ruby` means, no matter where you are.
- Ruby finds the file you specify (in the above example, `Matz.rb`) by looking in the current directory. To re-iterate, it is looking in whatever folder is written right there in your prompt.
- You can tell ruby to look outside the current folder by specifying the full path (as shown in the answer above).

To go from a new command window that you've just opened, to typing `ruby Matz.rb` and having it work, you need to do the following:

1. Move to the correct directory
2. Run the command

If we assume your username is `alex` and you have a folder *on your desktop* called "rubycode", which contains `Matz.rb`, you could do this:

1. Open a command prompt, which will most likely start in `C:\Users\Alex`
2. Move to the rubycode folder on your desktop: `cd Desktop\rubycode`. All subsequent commands will be working from within this folder.
3. Run the `ruby` command, specifying the file: `ruby Matz.rb`
4. Continue to run ruby commands as you learn ruby.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: How can I avoid doing this? Is there a shortcut? But this did work. Thanks! How can I do it the normal way such as "ruby matz.rb"?

Comment: Er... no, not really. It's a fundamental fact of how the command line environment operates. You could automate the selection of what folder you start in by setting up a shortcut to cmd.exe and setting the "working directory" in the shortcut...? I would edit the answer with a screenshot but I'm not at a Windows PC right now... The other approach is simply to `cd` into the right place once and keep using that window.

Comment: But where should I save it in order for the command line to recognize it when I type "ruby matz.rb" then?

Comment: What directory does your command prompt open in? I suspect it's probably `C:\Users\YourUsername` but just splatting all your files in there might get messy. Honestly, it sounds to me like you're new to the command line environment and just need to get a little more comfortable with it. It will feel more natural given a little time :-)

Comment: c:users\alex (alex is my username). I really want to start learning ruby but in my book they keep suggesting to type Matz.rb. Should I save my file in the Ruby folder?

Comment: Two approaches then... either save your files directly into that folder (I still don't think this is your best bet), or move into your desktop folder first using `cd` or by setting up a shortcut as I suggested. Either way, once you're there, typing `ruby Matz.rb` will do what it should.

Comment: directly in to what folder? The original ruby folder? what do u mean by cd? Is there anyway u could email me or I could email you? I'm really new. Thanks for your help really.

Comment: I've attempted to explain in depth. I really would urge you to stick with it though. It might seem alien to you now if it's not something you're used to, but it will all fall into place.